# @task docker tasks breaking after 3hrs of instance being spun up

Tags: docker, airflow, dockeroperator

Until last week all my airflow dags that were built in a task flow [@task docker] structure were working fine. Then all of sudden they started breaking. So I trialled restarting my instance which fixed the problem in the short term. But I noticed that once the image had been running for about 2-4hrs the same problem would occur.

error:

airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Docker container failed: {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 137} lines + python3 -c 'import base64, os;x = base64.b64decode(os.environ["__PYTHON_SCRIPT"]);f = open("/tmp/script.py", "wb"); f.write(x);'

How can I fix this issue?

I was expecting the task to run normally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.